# Buy X and Get a discount off Y (Different SKU)

Tags: shopping-cart-price-rules

I’m trying to implement a rule where a customer can order a Chocolate Éclair for $2 when they buy any other product. I’ve tried all sorts of combinations, with the shopping cart rules and I’ve worked out how to implement the right discount when the Chocolate Éclair SKU is chosen, alongside any other products.

Unfortunately it seems to be showing up when there’s one chocolate éclair in there as well.

Is there anyway you can help me out and show me how to implement this rule please, or even let me know whether it is possible, as this is going to be one of our offers moving forward so I need to ensure that it works this week.

For now i have simply offered the opportunity to get a Chocolate Eclair for $2 with any purchase through an attribute

Answer (score 0):

In your Magento shopping cart price rule, under the `conditions` tab, try a setup like this:

[image]

This should add two conditions that both need to be fulfilled to give the discount.

1. There should be an item in the cart with the Chocolate Éclair SKU; and
2. There should also be another item in the cart with a SKU other than (**is not**) Chocolate Éclair

> Please also note that `Use for Promo Rule Conditions` in the frontend
>   properties section of the `SKU <attribute>` has to be set to `Yes`.

Let me know if this works!